# Write a query that displays the names of cities and their countries when the capital city is the largest of all cities listed for that country

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have a database called `world`.
This database has two tables: `city` and `country`.

`city`'s columns are: `name`, `ID`, `Population`, `countryCode`.

`country`'s columns are: `Code`, `name`, `countryPopulation`, `Capital`.

- `countryCode` in `city` table = `Code` in `country` table
- `ID` in `city` table = `capital` in `country` table

Write a query that displays the names of cities and their countries when the capital city is the largest of all cities listed for that country.

Here is the code that displays the largest cities list:

```
SELECT MAX(c.Population) AS Population, c.Name AS City, cou.Name AS Country
FROM city c, country cou
WHERE c.CountryCode = cou.Code
GROUP BY cou.Name
```

Suppose I have that information from previous code:

```
Population    City             Country
1000000       Washington DC    USA
993943210     Sao Paulo        Brazil
1911919       Dubai            UAE
```

My query should show all cities in the USA because Washington DC is the capital of USA and all cities in the UAE because Dubai is the capital of UAE but should not show cities in Brazil because Sao Paulo is not the capital of Brazil.

Comment: How do you know if  the city is the capital ?

Comment: c.ID = cou.Capital

Comment: You mean get the list of cities of that country sorted with population? Please rephrase the description and title appropriately.

Comment: No. I need to get all cities of the country if the country capital list in largest cities

Comment: update your question and show a proper set of data and the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT c.name AS city_name, cou.name AS country_name
FROM city c LEFT JOIN country cou ON c.countrycode = cou.code
            LEFT JOIN city c2 ON cou.capital = c2.id
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT countrycode, MAX(population) AS max_pop
                       FROM city
                       GROUP BY countrycode) t 
                         ON cou.code = t.countrycode
WHERE c2.population = t.max_pop
```

The second `LEFT JOIN` allows to get the population of the country's capital (`c2.population`).

The third `LEFT JOIN` allows to get the population of the country's biggest city (`t.max_pop`).

And we keep only the cities where these two numbers are equal.

Comment: this answer gives me only one row

Comment: previous code show only Cities of the first country in the database which is Afghanistan

Answer (score 1):

You need your customer's names as well as the names of the cities in which they live. The names of the cities are stored in a separate table called "cities".

```
RIGHT
SELECT customers.name, cities.name
FROM customers
OUTER JOIN cities
ON cities.id=customers.city_id;
```